# Why/when do some elements are added to my dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code snippet, which finds the most frequent strings given a length k.

```
def FrequentWords(Text, k):
    patternDict = {}

    for i in range((len(Text)-k+1)):
        if Text[i:i+k] in patternDict:
            patternDict[Text[i:i+k]] += 1
        else:
            patternDict[Text[i:i+k]] = 1
```

The code works, but, I don't understand why Keys and Values start to be added to the initially empty dictionary 'patternDict'. I understand that `patternDict[Text[i:i+k]] = x` looks for the Key `Text[i:i+k]` and assign x to the respective Value but to me that line doesn't indicate that any element has to be added to the dictionary as indeed does.

To clarify, I understand what the code does, it is just the "adding action" of the lines 
`patternDict[Text[i:i+k]] = x` what I don't understand, because to me what any of those lines are saying is   "look for this Key and on its respective value."

Comment: the first line checks if the key already exists, if it does increment its value if not the next line adds that new key and sets the value to 1, a collections.defaultdict would be better and actually a collections.Counter would be even better

Comment: `patternDict[Text[i:i+k]] = 1` is doing the adding.

Comment: I do know which line is doing the adding as I state in my post and  @Padrai cCunningham  I also understand what the if line does but I just  don't understand why the line which is doing the adding does that, i guess i have to accept it and get used to it.

Comment: @matrs, I added an explanatory answer. If that does not make it clear explain what you don't get

Answer (score 0):

The first line checks if the key already exists, if it does increments the value if not then the else statement gets executed which adds that new key to the dict  and sets the value to 1, why the first line increments is because you want to count the times you see the substring/key in the string:

```
def FrequentWords(Text, k):
    patternDict = {}
    for i in range((len(Text)-k+1)):
        # if keys exists we have seen the substring before so increment its value by 1
        if Text[i:i+k] in patternDict:
            patternDict[Text[i:i+k]] += 1
        # else we have not seen this key before so add it to our dict
        else:
            patternDict[Text[i:i+k]] = 1
    return patternDict
```

A better method would be using a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def frequentWords(text, k):
    pattern_dict = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range((len(text)-k+1)):
        pattern_dict[text[i:i+k]] += 1
    return pattern_dict
```

Comment: Thanks, i edited my OP to clarify my question. As you see, the "adding action" of the line was what i dind't understand, because i thought that was a way to assign or in general operate over a dict Value but not to add a Key to a dictionary. I thought i needed other statement to add a key to my dictionary and then look for any key and operate over its value.

Comment: the `patternDict[Text[i:i+k]] = 1` is exactly how you add a new key, how did you think you added a new key to  a dict?

Comment: Yes , indeed was a pretty dumb question, indeed checking the python documentation , which i did when i begun studying dictionaries i found this: tel['guido'] = 4127 , then you have added a Key and assigned a Value. Sorry

Comment: @matrs, I have seen much worse questions